# Cocoa disabling a NSTextField

Tags: cocoa

Ok, I am working on a Cocoa app and I cannot get the text field to disable when the "Default Source" button is clicked. The cursor by default is in this text field when the program starts. When I click the default source button, the text field is not disabled until I manually click on another field and thus remove the cursor from the source text field. How do I make the text field disable immediately even though the cursor is there? Even if the cursor isn't there, the text field won't disable until I move the cursor there, and then back to another field.

I don't yet have 10 reputation... here is the link to the picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bu0OG.png

Currently, this is the only line of code that is in the function that is called when you click "default source":

```
sourcePath.enabled = NO;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try checking if your on the main thread before disabling by:

```
NSLog(@"is main thread: %d", [NSThread isMainThread]);
```

If your not, then you can:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    sourcePath.enabled = NO;
});
```

This code may be a little inaccurate as my background comes from iOS...

Comment: This is what it told me: 
2014-06-09 11:41:38.648 TTU Backup[52465:303] is main thread: 1

Comment: Ok, I am very new to Cocoa and I just realized that I had object's received actions linked incorrectly. I fixed it, and now it works perfectly. Thanks for the help though!